# Paypal Java SOAP GetExpressCheckoutDetails fails in SDK 2.2.98

Tags: java, soap, paypal

we try to integrate Paypal as a payment option in our shop.
For this we selected the merchant SDK with the SOAP api (Version 2.2.98)

The first step with SetExpressCheckoutAPI works fine,
but in the second step when we retrieve the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API we always receive this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NONE
urn.ebay.apis.eBLBaseComponents.AddressNormalizationStatusCodeType.fromValue(AddressNormalizationStatusCodeType.java:32)
urn.ebay.apis.eBLBaseComponents.AddressType.<init>(AddressType.java:631)
urn.ebay.apis.eBLBaseComponents.PaymentDetailsType.<init>(PaymentDetailsType.java:981)
urn.ebay.apis.eBLBaseComponents.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetailsType.<init>(GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetailsType.java:627)
urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseType.<init>(GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseType.java:78)
urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.getExpressCheckoutDetails(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.java:2855)
urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.getExpressCheckoutDetails(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.java:2875)
com.sample.merchant.CheckoutServlet.doPost(CheckoutServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

To verify the behaviour we also used the sample application included with the SDK and it shows the very same problem.

Any ideas ?
Is this a bug in the SDK/Java wrapper ?

Comment: Here the XML answer I receive from the SOAP request:

`<ShipToAddress xsi:type="ebl:AddressType">
                        <AddressStatus xsi:type="ebl:AddressStatusCodeType">None</AddressStatus>
                        <AddressNormalizationStatus xsi:type="ebl:AddressNormalizationStatusCodeType">NONE</AddressNormalizationStatus>
                    </ShipToAddress>
'

Seems to be a mapping problem...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known problem with 98 SDK release.

Using the 96 SDK works fine.
The corresponding jar can be found in the maven repository.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paypal.sdk/merchantsdk/2.1.96

https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-java/issues/3